# Jetbrains Rider can you change "Comment with line comment" to use 4 slashes instead of 2?

Tags: configuration, jetbrains-rider

We are using Jetbrains Rider to do our .Net C# projects.
If I have a code block that I'm currently working on and want to try something else, I usually just comment out the lines, using the "Comment with line comment" shortcut.

This changes the marked area, adding double slahes in front of the code lines, like so:

```
before:
var contact1 = new Contact();
var contact2 = new Contact();

after shortcut was used
// var contact1 = new Contact();
// var contact2 = new Contact();
```

This however gives me a violation of [SA1515](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1515.md) saying:
Single-line comment should be preceded by blank line
AND
Single-line comments should not be followed by blank line (on line 2,3,4 etc)

There is a hack to cirkumvent that rule however, being adding 4 slashes instead of 2 and the validator will ignore the violation.
This would give the following outcome of the same shortcut:

```
//// var contact1 = new Contact();
//// var contact2 = new Contact();
```

Does anybody know if and where Rider can be modified, so Rider will add 4 slashes instead, when using "Comment with line comment" shortcut?

I tried googling the issue, but I could not find a solution.
It seems VSCode can handle this though, but we are not using VSCode at work.

Comment: I do not know and do not use Jetbrains Rider but if it is indeed not configurable, a workaround might be using block comments instead of line comments.

Comment: Hi, yeah, but I like single line comments, when removing larger blocks of code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to use `////` instead of `//`, which makes sense (at least to me ) as the C# language spec explicitly says ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/comments)):

> C# supports two different forms of comments. **Single line comments start with `//` and end at the end of that line of code**. Multiline comments start with `/*` and end with `*/`.

I'd recommend adjusting your StyleCop rules, either via `.DotSettings` or `.editorconfig`.

Comment: Yeah, that might be the way to go locally. AFAIK it's treated as an error on our test servers, if any stylecop rules fail. And i'm not sure that the test server respects .editorconfig or .DotSettings.